# Rspec Create/Update Unknown Attribute Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm using the latest versions of Rails, Rspec and Factory Girl and I'm getting a strange issue when I try to test my create or update logic. The controller in question is an Admin namespaced PostsController and the model is Post. The factory itself just creates a post with a title and a body.

```
describe 'create' do
before :all do
    @new = Factory.build(:post)
end

it 'should be successful' do
  post :create, :post => @new
  response.should be_success
end

describe 'failure' do
  it 'should not create a new page' do
    lambda do
      post :create, :post => @new
    end.should_not change(Post, :count)
  end

  it 'should render the new template' do
    post :create, :post => @new
    response.should render_template('new')
  end
end
```

end

The error I keep receiving is:

> ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
>          unknown attribute: post

I'm probably doing something extremely stupid but I'm just lost right now.

**UPDATE**

Just in case anyone should ever stumble across this...

I was doing something extremely stupid. I had an error in my controller where instead of calling Post.new(params[:post]) I was calling Post.new(params)...

Comment: By the way, I know two of those tests above will fail but I'd like them to fail for the right reasons. My plan was to go back and add a real fail case once I was sure everything was working.

Answer (score 2):

It would help to know what line it's failing on. If it's failing in the 'before :all' block, then the problem is probably in your factory code, which is presumably specifying a value for a non-existent 'post' attribute of the model.

If that's what the factory is doing, but the 'post' attribute actually should exist, then perhaps you ran this using `rspec` from the command line without running `rake db:test:prepare` first. In that case, your 'posts' table structure might not be up to date.

Comment: It is failing on the post :create line every time. I have run db:test:prepare as well and I've checked (just because...) to make sure everything was up to date in the DB.